# Problem with memory in Queue which works in several threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue, out-of-memory

My program works with a queue and a large file. I work with the queue in several threads and at some point there is OutOfMemoryException because of having too many objects Enqueued in the first thread in the queue. They do not manage to Dequeue in the second thread as fast as required.

P.S. I can use just the primitives of synchronyzing (Thread, Monitor)

I've already written a code which works with not very big data. I know that I can do Thread.Sleep (and this is works, I thried) when in my queue exists definite amount of objects. As far as I know it's not the best solution

```
class SynchronizedQueue
{
    protected readonly object locker = new object();

    protected Queue<BlockData> queue = new Queue<BlockData>();

    public int Counter { get; set; }

    public bool IsClose { get; set; }

    public bool TryDequeue(out BlockData blockData)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            while (queue.Count == 0)
            {
                if (IsClose)
                {
                    blockData = new BlockData();
                    return false;
                }
                Monitor.Wait(locker);
            }

            blockData = queue.Dequeue();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            IsClose = true;
            Monitor.PulseAll(locker);
        }
    }

    public void Enqueue(BlockData blockData)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            //That's what i want to avoid
            if (Counter == 1000)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(240);
            }
            if (IsClose)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Work was canceled!");

            while (blockData.Id != Counter)
                Monitor.Wait(locker);

            queue.Enqueue(blockData);
            Counter++;
            Monitor.PulseAll(locker);
        }
    }
}
```

What can you recommend for synchronizing Enqueue/Dequeue and avoid OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: There's nothing in your description that tells us what you need to do, except to say that you need to make sure that you don't put too much in the queue. If you want a better answer than that you need to show us your code and, ideally, give us a [mcve].

Comment: @Enigmativity, I add the code!

Comment: You need a [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Concurrent_BlockingCollection_1__ctor_System_Int32_) where you can set a bound capacity